# How to use the Theme Page reactions in context

Tags: 7, theming

In the context module, how does the reaction Theme Page work? I am confused how to use it in my theme

I am using an Omega subtheme and want to display the Section title used in the context to show up in a region. How can I get this value to show?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a theme preprocess hook to pass the variable to the right zone template. Here's how I added it to my header zone:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_zone(&$vars) {
    $zone = $vars['zone'];

    if ('header' == $zone) {
        $theme = alpha_get_theme();

        // set via context module
        if (isset($theme->page['section_title'])) {
            $vars['section_title'] = $theme->page['section_title'];
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your zone--header.tpl.php file

```
<?php if (isset($section_title)): ?>
<div class="grid-<?php print $columns ?>">
    <h1 class="section-title"><?= $section_title ?></h1>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```